# Oauth login popup not closing in ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have written javascript code for oauth login popup for google OAuth 
code is as follows

```
    function authorize(authorize_url,get_token,get_token_secret)
    {
        console.log("acToken is "+get_token);

    var win         =   window.open(authorize_url, "windowname2", "width=800, height=600"); 

   var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() { 
       try
       {
       if (win.document.URL.indexOf(oauth_callback) != -1) {
           console.log("url inside callback"+win.document.URL)
           window.clearInterval(pollTimer);

           win.close();

           getting_access_token(get_token,get_token_secret);
       }
       }catch(e)
       {

       }
   },100);
}
```

in that window is opening oauth but after click allow it is not going inside if of window.setinterval function that's why popup window is not closing in ie in firefox and chrome window is closing properly how to resolve this in ie.

Answer (score 0):

You should open login page in a new window, then redirect to a success page, which then closes the popup:

page.html

```
function login() {
    var win = window.open('', 'login.html', 'width=800,height=400');
    win.focus();
}
```

login.html

```
window.location.href = 'success.html'; // or use server-side redirect
```

success.html

```
window.opener.close();
```